# Issue with log4j version 2.9.0 in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, log4j

I am using log4j in one of my Android lib projects. Now I updated the log4j version from 2.3.0 to 2.9.0 and building the lib project is successful and also I was able to successfully add this lib project to my main project as a dependency. But when I run my project, I get the following error.

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>       Cause: Dex cannot parse version 53 byte code.
>       This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
>       If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add
>       targetCompatibility = '1.7'
>       sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
>       to that submodule's build.gradle file.
>       ...while parsing META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class

To over come the above error I made the following changes in the gradle.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        ...        
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

After the above changes I got the following error while running the project.

> Error:Jar transformation: class files coming from an unsupported Java
>   version Error:Execution failed for task
>
> ':MyApp:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception

Now I am not getting a proper solution for this problem. Even I raised this in log4j forum (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2038). But the provided solution doesn't explain much.

Mean while I am trying to work directly with the log4j android code from [here](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/tree/android) .

This has become a blocker for me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried disabling jack?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you running? (2.2.3 or lower or 3.0 canary)?

Comment: @MatPag : Java-8 needs jack to be enabled. Else it throws the following error. Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

Comment: @LunaWatcher : It's 2.3.1 on MAC

Comment: Jack has been deprecated: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html, https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html. Have you tried upgrading to a beta release of Android Studio 3.0 with Java 8 integrated?

Comment: Yes. Android Studio 3.0 Beta 5 also throws the same issue.

Comment: that's strange :/ obviously you cleaned the project, right?

Comment: @MatPag : Ohh yeah.. several times.

Comment: manually deleting the builds folders and rebuild?

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: i'm out of options... probably you should downgrade to 2.3.0 or the maximum working version for you until you find the cause of the problem. Good luck

Comment: I got the same issue.. Any update on this?